# Mattermost password reset and email verification is broken

Tags: mattermost

I tried to log-in. It would not let me because first I needed to confirm my email address. No email received to do so, not even after several attempts. I decided to reset my password. I do receive that email. The password was reset but I cannot log-in with it. After a second attempt to reset the password I must conclude the system is broken.

I still receive the chat notifications and have reset the password with the same email address, which apparently is not verified. So why does it send notifications to an unverified email address then?

This kind of sucks, don't you agree? How to end my account there? User is null

Comment: I've posted a link into infrastructure on chat hopefully someone there can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to login to your account by temporarily changing the email associated with it.

I do see in the logs that the email you had set is invalid. Your email server is responding "User unknown". I see `div@[...]`, could it be a typo for `dev@[...]`?

Comment: Yes you were right.